# AWS CodeDeploy agent can't deploy code if EC2 instance has no public IP?

Tags: aws-code-deploy

I've implemented an AutoScaling Group with a CodeDeploy agent system. Everything works fine if I set up the launch template to starts EC2 instances with a public IPv4, but if I disable this, the CodeDeploy agent is stuck on waiting at the "ApplicationStop" step (the first one) that is never executed.

I suspect that AWS can't access my EC2 properly to communicate with the local CodeDeploy-Agent (which is running fine from the `service codedeploy-agent status` call).

As soon as I add back a public IPv4, everything works fine.

How can I configure my settings (SecurityGroup? Role?) to allow CodeDeploy to work fine with a private EC2 instance?

### Update 1

The EC2 instances have the role "aws-elasticbeanstalk-ec2-role" which contains the following strategy:

- AWSElasticBeanstalkWebTier
- AmazonS3ReadOnlyAccess
- AWSElasticBeanstalkMulticontainerDocker
- AWSElasticBeanstalkWorkerTier

Maybe the issue is here: I need to add a "CodeDeploy" strategy, but when trying to attach one related to CodeDeploy, there are many and I'm not sure which one to use to have

Comment: Your instances are in your vpc and need access to the CodeDeploy endpoint (e.g https://codedeploy.us-east-2.amazonaws.com) , either over the internet or using a VPC endpoint (They don't automatically have this access just because they are in an AWS vpc). For your private instances to access code deploy you would likely need either of a NAT gateway, NAT instance or setup the VPC endpoints for the Codeploy